# Oracle SQL Nested Loop, which relation is in the OUTER FOR LOOP?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL Developer, made a query and this is the plan of the query:

[image: Nested Loop]

How could I know, which one is the outer, and which one is the inner loop and what are the record numbers?

And a second question: which index the oracle using?

Comment: As far as I know it's the first one (investors in your example)

Comment: SHow the query too please